# Starting debugger in RubyMine gives internal error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubymine

When starting ruby debugger in RubyMine, I'm getting next error:

```
runnerw.exe E:\jruby-1.6.7.2\bin\jruby.exe --1.9 -X+O
-J-Djruby.reflection=true -J-Djruby.compile.mode=OFF -J-Djruby.debug.fullTrace=true -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) E:/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta17/bin/rdebug-ide --debug --port 64311 --dispatcher-port 64312 -- E:/Workspace_Java&Ruby/Project_3_3/script/rails server -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -e development Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17.beta17, ruby-debug-base 0.10.5.rc3) listens on 127.0.0.1:64311 Connected from 127.0.0.1 

12348: Starting control thread 
12348: Processing in control: b E:/Workspace_Java&Ruby/Project_3_3/app/controllers/login_controller.rb:9 
12348: <breakpointAdded no="1" location="E:/Workspace_Java&Ruby/Project_3_3/app/controllers/login_controller.rb:9"/> 
12348: <error> 
12348: INTERNAL ERROR!!! IOError

12348: </error> 12348: <error>
```

Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: Wild quess, `&` in `Workspace_Java&Ruby` directory name may be causing a problem. See if it works with a new project located in some other directory.

Comment: If you add it as answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` in `Workspace_Java&Ruby` directory name may be causing a problem, moving a project to a different directory should help.